# Why does bitwise AND with byte in JAVA do this?

Tags: java, char, byte, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm messing around with bitwise operators, and I was trying to convert a negative byte to an unsigned 8 bit value, and this is what people suggested:

```
System.out.println(-20 & 0xFF); //bitwise AND on negative number and 255
```

So, this works perfectly, and returns 236, but why? As far as I'm concerned:

```
00010100 //binary representation of -20
11111111 //binary representation of 0xFF or 255
--------
00010100 //it returns the same exact thing, so it's either -20 or 20
```

Why does it work? I think I've missed something pretty simple, but I can't seem to grasp it.

Also, if I do it with a positive number below 256, it returns the same number. I can't seem to understand what Java does with these numbers.

Comment: -20 != 20 and so the representation is not the same either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literals in Java are in the form of `int`. So when you say `-20 & 0xFF`, this is what happens:

```
  11111111 11111111 11111111 11101100 //-20 -ve nos are stored in 2's compliment form
& 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 // 0xFF 
  -------- -------- -------- --------
  00000000 00000000 00000000 11101100 // 236
```

Since the negetaive values are stored in 2's compliment form, you get the value 236.

When you perfrom `20 & 0xFF`, this happens:

```
  00000000 00000000 00000000 00010100 // 20 -ve nos are stored in 2's compliment form
& 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 // 0xFF 
  -------- -------- -------- --------
  00000000 00000000 00000000 00010100 // 20
```

Comment: Ah, I get it now. It's probably the 2's compliment form that confused me. So let me get this straight: If I save a negative number between -128 and -1 (inclusive), it gets saved as a 7 bit representation of 256 minus that number, and the 8th bit is used solely to represent whether it's negative or positive, is that right? Now, the only thing that confused me a bit, is that in the first example, 24 1's are appended at the start of the -20. Why 1's, and why not 0's? That's the only thing that's bothering me right now.

Comment: @user1007059: If you have a `byte` variable, then the 8th bit is used for storing the sign. But when you have a literal, as in the above case, the literals are stored as `int`, no matter how small the size might be. So when you write `-20 & 0xFF`, two `ints` are created of 32 bit each, and the MSB, i.e. the 32nd bit is used for storing the sign. In the 1st example, the preceding 1's are present because of the number is in 2's compliment and in 2's compliment form, ALL the bits before the 1st 1 are flipped, i.e. 0s become 1s and 1s become 0.

Comment: Alright thanks, I now understand most of this. I can continue messing around with bits and bytes without feeling like an idiot :D

Answer (score 1):

A byte is a signed value held in 8 bits and may be in the range -128 to 127.

The left most bit is used as the sign bit.

`System.out.println(-20 & 0xFF);` has nothing to do with bytes, this is an int operation.

The binary representation of -20, as a byte is: 1110_1100

1110_1100 & 1111_1111 = 1110_1100

If you want unsigned, there's char to play with, but you're not going to be happy. Realistically, Java doesn't have unsigned.

Negatives are stored in '2s Complement' form, eg:

1111_1111 == -1

But why?

Under 2s complement to make a negative number, all the bits are flipped (1s complement) and 1 is added (making 2s complement - two operations)

So

```
 0000_0000 - Zero
-0000_0001 - minus one
 ---------
 1111_1110 - Ones complement - (this would be xor 1111_1111)
+0000_0001 - plus one - we're converting to 2s complement, not doing math
 ---------
 1111_1111 - -1 in 2s complement
```

Comment: I said "byte" because I tried storing the -20 inside of a byte and then doing the & 0xFF thing, and it did work. 

Also, 11101100, wouldn't that be -108? The left most bit represents the minus, and the rest represents the actual number, which would be 108. What am I missing here?

Comment: There are only two places where the missing unsigned really demands your additional attention: relational operators and widending conversions. Switching to char is mostly stupid, since almost any operations on it will result in an int with all the gorry signed problems back (but now hidden in an intermediate result). Getting to know the details of twos-complement allows you to properly work with unsigned data even when the variables are treated as signed. There is no adequate replacement for knowledge, not in java nor any other language.

Comment: I'm just starting with paying attention to the size of datatypes and whether they're signed/unsigned etc. I've always blindly used int or long for numbers, but right now I'm messing around with something that requires bit of a deeper understanding of datatypes, that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @Durandal He's experimenting with bits, not designing a nuclear power plant control system. There is no 'stupid', there is only learning.

Comment: Yeah, the same could be said about the programmers that crashed an Ariane 5 rocket because they did not bother to handle overflow with a narrowing cast. Guess they were just playing with bits, too (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_%28spacecraft%29#Arithmetic_Overflow). I call giving an advice (switch to char) that causes more trouble than it solves 'stupid'. Just my opinion.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how bitwise operators work, and how bits are stored in programming languages. I assume that a child has to fall once in a while before he learns to walk perfectly, or do you tell a kid he's an idiot because he can't stand up straight with his brittle legs? I understand what you mean, but the fact of the matter is that I need to learn how these things work, in one way or another. If I get to program a rocket some day, I'll try not to fall on my ass.

Comment: @Durandal I noted that char is the only unsigned option and that results would be unexpected, hardly advocating usage of char in rocket systems.

Comment: user1007059, I don't get why you feel my comment was addressing you, that was never my intention. Of course you have to play with things to learn. And yes, you will fall and get up again. Nothing wrong with that. My comment was solely addressing *one single part* of RayStojonics *answer*, which I feel would have better been left out. That 'switch to char' in an attempt to get usigned behavior, delaying the need to know how twos-complement works for a bit. It would be ok advice for a language that can handle unsigned. In java its just a recipe to get into deeper trouble.

Comment: I see, Durandal, I guess the "programmers that crashed an Ariane 5 rocket" example kind of felt like it was more directed towards the student, rather than the teacher. I guess that wasn't the case. Still, thanks Ray for the answer, it really helped me understand this.